# How to List all files in a directory and export result to a text file?

Tags: linux, command-line

How to list all files (order by name) in a Linux directory/subdir, and then export result to a txt file?
Help me please!!! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use [find](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) as below

```
find /path/to/dir -type f -printf '%p\n' > /path/to/file
```

every regular file in /path/to/dir will have it's absolute path printed out and uses [bash redirection](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) to /path/to/file

To have them sorted you would need to pipe through sort.

```
find /path/to/dir -type f -printf '%p\n' | sort > /path/to/file
```

this will sort by full path to sort by basename

```
find /path/to/dir -type f -printf '%f::%p\n' | sort | awk -F'::' '{ $1=""; print }' > /path/to/file
```

this will print the basename of the file first, sort on that then awk removes the initial filename and redirects just the absolute path into the file.

Comment: this list (as david requested) only files (and not links, char special files, pipes, etc), but maybe he meant "not directories" ? in that case instead of `-type f` use `! -type d` . And "-ls" instead of "-print" will print lots of additionnal info instead of just filename, if needed.

Comment: I think this is more Useful
`code`ls -R /path/to/folder/| grep -v /| sort > /path/to/file.txt
But i dont know how to soft results by file-size?

Comment: `ls` has an option for that.

Comment: using ls -RS will not sort all files by size, only by size in each directory. eg a dir with 3 dirs in will display the 3 dirs in standard order, ( unless they have so many contents that they are larger than the std 4096 b) then the contents of each dir in size order.

Answer (score 1):

The following will export all directories in the current folder into a file.  Remember to be in the directory which has all the folders:

```
ls >> /path/to/file
```